# Save variable to RAM for other script use?

Tags: php, memory-management

Is there anyway i can save the value of `$x` into the RAM or any other place
(rather than HDD , database , cookie , session)

so it can be re-used after a while
(read again from another script/read again from the same script/modified) ?

Comment: What's wrong with writing it to disk or a database?

Comment: database is overused by simple function of increasing the views for a post by one for example , you can save the views count of a post into the memory , then save them to the database every 10 minutes for example if you're gettng like 100000 views/hour ! . saving resources is a must in large websites ;)

Comment: If you so desperately need to save your resources to this extent, you should already be using APC or memcache, together with database query caching, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is RAM?**

random-access memory

The closer you can use is [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

Comment: or APC, or shmem (if you're feeling adventurous)

Comment: is true ... memcache is work better in distributed environment or multiple servers